# SAPUI5 Custom Control Binding

Tags: binding, controls, sapui5

I am trying to figure out how to bind a data model to a custom control. I have searched a number of similar questions here but they don't seem to match what I am trying to do. Maybe my method is wrong.

Anyway, I have created a Plunkr (https://plnkr.co/edit/UghwOObcDn1oRndOpCeJ) to demonstrate. Two input fields are created, one of which is on a custom control which extends a sap.m.Panel. I am attempting to bind the **name** and **enabled** properties to both input fields. No problem with the simple sap.m.Input on the page but the one in the custom control **MyPanel** no such luck. The **name** and **enabled** properties for both input fields should change when the button is pressed.

For the custom control I am trying to pass the bind properties to the **value** and **enabled** properties of the embedded input field as can be seen in App.view.xml.

If I change the following in MyPanel.js:

```
value: mSettings.value,
enabled: mSettings.enabled
```

to

```
value: '{/name}',
enabled: '{/editing}'
```

all works fine.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/68899274/5846045, your custom control is missing `oRm.writeControlData(oControl)` in your render function. Custom setters and getters, as suggested by the answer below, aren't required to get it work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom UI5 control does not update bound value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68899274/custom-ui5-control-does-not-update-bound-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to define the 'value' and 'enabled' properties in your custom control. To get the binding working you need to have custom setter/getter methods in your extended control. These methods are called on binding updates.

Here is the updated [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/wUjjtPzQxUUkvMUiK0fj?p=preview)

```
sap.m.Panel.extend('my.App.MyPanel', {
 constructor: function(mSettings) {
 sap.m.Panel.apply(this, arguments);

 this.ef = new sap.m.Input({
   width: '100px',
   value: mSettings.value,
   enabled: mSettings.enabled
 });

 this.setAggregation('_ef', this.ef);
 },

 metadata: {
   properties: {
     enabled: { type: 'boolean', defaultValue: true },
     value: { type: 'String', defaultValue: "" }
  },

   events: {
   },

   aggregations: {
     _ef: { type: 'sap.m.Input', multiple: false, visibility: 'hidden' }
   }
 },

 init: function() {
 },

 renderer: function(oRM, oControl) {
   oRM.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation('_ef'));
 },

 setValue: function (sValue) {
   this.ef.setValue(sValue);
 },

 setEnabled: function (bValue) {
   this.ef.setEnabled(bValue);
 },

 getValue: function(){
   return this.ef.getProperty("value");
 },

 getEnabled: function(){
  return this.ef.getProperty("enabled");
 }

});
```

Comment: Hmmm. I copied your code into Plunker. Still no go.